# Empty result set in MySQL gets translated to Result Set with empty row in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I was just going through some logs in my application and I noticed a query which was badly written (by me) and it was getting executed very frequently. The query had couple joins with a subquery with group concat.

I tried to optimize this query and I have something which is better in performance multifold and would really help our application.

```
SELECT table1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.gid) as gids, GROUP_CONCAT(table3.items) as items from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 using (ID) LEFT JOIN table3 USING (ID) WHERE table1.Status != 4 AND table1.ID = <insert_an_id> group by ID;
```

Its really weird that when I execute this query with table1.ID to be an ID which does not exist, MySQL returns a result set with a row with all NULLs. It suspect it was due to the group concats, but due to my limited MySql knowledge, I could not be certain. It works fine when I do not filter it on ID.

To fix this problem I added a HAVING clause to this query.

```
 HAVING table1.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Now, **MySql returns an empty set, but I notice that JDBC returns a result set with one row. All elements in this row are Nulls. Since I am using Spring, I expect the NamedParameterJDBCTemplate to throw an EmptyResultSet Exception.** I am using JDBC 4, MySql 5.5.39, and Java 6.

Please let me know if there is anymore information I can provide. Thanks a bunch in advance.

**EDIT : The suggestion from 'GreyBreardedGeek' solved my problem for the time being. How stupid of me to miss the group by. 
However, It still sounds like a very ambiguous behavior in JDBC despite of MySql returning an empty set. It would be great if someone can provide a valid explanation of why am I seeing this behavior. Thanks.**

Comment: Is your sample SQL correct? You are using GROUP_CONCAT, but you don't have a GROUP BY clause...

Comment: Hi GreyBeardedGeek, I apologize for the late reply and thanks for pointing out. I have edited the query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That was exactly my issue.